# In c++, where is std::alloc defined

Tags: c++

I'm reading a Chinese book, in English that is called "The analysis of STL source code". There is something about `std::allocator` and`std::alloc`, but i can only find `std::allocator`. My question is where is `std::alloc`. Is it deleted from STL?

Comment: Exists (or existed) in `stl::` does not exist in `std::`.  See also: https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/alloc.html  Note that `stl` is not `std`.

Comment: Maybe related there is also `std::calloc`, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/calloc).

Comment: I havent heard of a `std::alloc` but there is a [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) and [`std::calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/calloc)